# How to save value after each click with ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have this function that run after I click the button

```
function Wo_GetMorePosts() {

    var query = $(".search-for-posts").val()

    if (search_status == "1"){

        Wo_SearchForPosts(query,1)

    }else{
        $.get(Wo_Ajax_Requests_File(), {
            f: 'posts',
            s: 'load_more_posts',
            filter_by_more: filter_by_more,
            after_post_id: after_post_id,
            user_id: user_id,
            page_id: page_id,
            group_id: group_id,
            posts_count: posts_count
        }, function (data) {
            if (data.length == 0) {
                $.get(Wo_Ajax_Requests_File(), {f: 'get_no_posts_name'}, function (data3) {
                    $('#load-more-posts').html('<div class="white-loading list-group"><div class="cs-loader"><div class="no-more-posts-to-show">' + data3.name + '</div></div>');
                });
            } else {
                $('#posts').append(data);
            }
        });

    }
    $('#load-more-posts').show();
    $('.loading-status').remove();
    Wo_progressIconLoader($('#load-more-posts'));
    scrolled = 0;
}
```

My problem is in `Wo_SearchForPosts(query,1)` I want to increase the second parameter (the number) after every click. So that the second click will be `Wo_SearchForPosts(query,2)`.

How Can I do make it?

Comment: Add a variable `var counter = 1;` above the `Wo_GetMorePosts()`-function. Replace the `Wo_SearchForPosts(query,1);` with `Wo_SearchForPosts(query,counter++);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a global variable counter and then increase the counter by one.

```
    var counter = 0;
    function Wo_GetMorePosts() {

        var query = $(".search-for-posts").val()

        if (search_status == "1"){
            Wo_SearchForPosts(query,++counter)
        }else{
            $.get(Wo_Ajax_Requests_File(), {
                f: 'posts',
                s: 'load_more_posts',
                filter_by_more: filter_by_more,
                after_post_id: after_post_id,
                user_id: user_id,
                page_id: page_id,
                group_id: group_id,
                posts_count: posts_count
            }, function (data) {
                if (data.length == 0) {
                    $.get(Wo_Ajax_Requests_File(), {f: 'get_no_posts_name'}, function (data3) {
                        $('#load-more-posts').html('<div class="white-loading list-group"><div class="cs-loader"><div class="no-more-posts-to-show">' + data3.name + '</div></div>');
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#posts').append(data);
                }
            });
        }
        $('#load-more-posts').show();
        $('.loading-status').remove();
        Wo_progressIconLoader($('#load-more-posts'));
        scrolled = 0;
    }
```